# Múltiples Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

He desagregado ciertas tablas de una bd que tenía y me encuentro intentando corregir las consultas hechas desde la aplicación cliente.

**person**

```
`id int(11) pk nn ai uq
name varchar(40) nn
lastname varchar(40) nn
phone varchar(25) null
user_id int(11) null uq (en principio es unique, aunque recién veo que no está seteado) fk -> user.id `
```

**user**

```
`id int(11) pk nn ai uq
username varchar(25) nn
userpass varchar(25) nn`
```

**position**

```
`id int(11) pk nn ai uq
charge_name varchar(40) nn`
```

**departament**

```
`id int(11) pk nn ai uq
departament_name varchar(40) nn`
```

**person_position**

```
`user_id int(11) null fk -> user.id
departament_id int(11) nn fk -> department.id
position_id int(11) nn fk -> position.id`
```

Para obtener los datos, intenté con:

```
`SELECT * 
FROM ((user INNER JOIN person_position ON user.id = person_position.user_id)
    INNER JOIN department ON department.id = person_position.department_id)
    INNER JOIN position ON position.id = person_position.position_id
WHERE user.username LIKE 'Juan' AND user.password LIKE 'Pérez';`
```

Bastante bien resultó, el hecho es que cuando quiero filtrar a través del SELECT los datos que voy a precisar, MySQL me devuelve un error:

**SQL**

```
`SELECT user.username, person.name, person.lastname, department.department_name, position.charge
FROM ((user INNER JOIN person_position ON user.id = person_position.user_id)
                INNER JOIN department ON department.id = person_position.department_id)
                INNER JOIN position ON position.id = person_position.position_id
WHERE user.username LIKE 'Juan' AND user.password LIKE 'Pérez';`
```

¿Alguna ayuda? Desde ya, muchas gracias :).

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda si pudieras agregar el error que recibes. Así mismo te diría que los errores son: 1. no existe `position.charge`, ya que debería ser `position.charge_name`. 2. no existe `user.password`, ya que debería ser `user.userpass`.

Comment: También añadir al comentario de @Marcos que, intentas obtener `person.name`, `person.lastname` cuando no estás haciendo ningun join a la tabla `person`.

Comment: Aparte de lo ya mencionado, siempre es bueno especificar el resultado deseado. Una cosa es que se te ayude a correr una consulta sin error, y otra es que te dé el resultado deseado.

Comment: Aparte de los tres comentarios anteriores, tampoco necesitas esos paréntesis, parece como si interpretases que a través de ellos hay algún tipo de prioridad al hacer los `JOIN`... No estoy seguro, pero podrían incluso provocar algún error.

Comment: Gracias a todos por las correcciones y los comentarios (ayudan y mucho). He podido resolverlo siguiendo los lineamientos que me indicaron. Les agradezco enormemente (pido disculpas por el tiempo de respuesta, pero he experimentado ciertos cortes en el servicio de internet y recién el día de hoy pude solucionarlo).